# How to force init a view controller before it is presented the first time?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with multiple view controllers.

I attempt to do a method call to one of the view controllers (lets call it `SomeViewController`) and I realised that `SomeViewController` was not initialised yet.

And `SomeViewController`will only be initialised when I click it's tab once.

So, is it possible to initialise the view controller even before the view of `initialise` is presented the first time?

Comment: This is not true. All the tab bar controller's view controllers are initialized before the tab bar controller itself is initialized.

Comment: Thank you. You made me realise where the problem is. I have a property in my AppDelegate and the reference is only assigned in the viewDidLoad of the view controller. All the while, I have been trying to access this property (which is obviously nil) even before the assignment was done.